# SyntaxNode ReplaceNode doesn't replace node

Tags: c#, roslyn-code-analysis, codefixprovider

I'm trying to replace a statement in code with something else entirely. From:

```
var results = item.Axes.GetDescendants();
```

To (something like):

```
using (var context = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("someindex").CreateSearchContext())
{
    IQueryable<SearchResultItem> searchQuery = Context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>().Where(item => item.Paths.Path.Contains("some arbitrary path"));
}
var results = searchQuery.GetResults();
```

To do so, I have this task:

```
context.RegisterCodeFix(
                CodeAction.Create(
                    title: title,
                    equivalenceKey: title,
                    createChangedDocument: c => RemoveDeclarationAsync(context.Document, nodeToRemove, c)
                    ),
                diagnostic);
```

`RemoveDeclarationAsync` looks like this:

```
private async Task<Document> RemoveDeclarationAsync(Document document, SyntaxNode declaration, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    SyntaxNode node = SyntaxFactory.ParseExpression(snippet);

    var syntaxRoot = (await document.GetSyntaxRootAsync());
    var newSyntax = syntaxRoot.ReplaceNode(declaration, node);
    return document.WithSyntaxRoot(newSyntax);
}
```

`snippet` is effectively the `using` statement as a string. `declaration` is the node to replace. However, when I debug this I get an error message:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.IdentifierNameSyntax' to type
>   'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.VariableDeclarationSyntax'.

Even though `declaration` and `node` are both defined as `SyntaxNode` it's not having it, because declaration is a `VariableDeclarationSyntax` and node is an `IdentifierNameSyntax`.

If I call `ReplaceNode` like so:

```
var newSyntax = syntaxRoot.ReplaceNode((SyntaxNode)declaration, (SyntaxNode)node);
```

the error goes away, but nothing actually happens, `newSyntax` is exactly the same as the original `syntaxRoot`.

How do I get the correct CodeFix for the old statement?

**edit**

If I use the statement `item.Axes.GetDescendants();` instead of the full `var results = item.Axes.GetDescendants();` as `declaration` it starts working. Of course, that's not entirely what I want, because I need the declaration part (`var results =`) also to be removed...

I've tried inserting the new node before the old one instead using `(await document.GetSyntaxRootAsync()).InsertNodesBefore(declaration, listOfOneNode)`, but that errors out.

Comment: What does `SyntaxFactory.ParseExpression(snippet)` return to your as a node? And I'm little confused that you try to replace the one Syntax node by two others node using just one `ReplaceNode` method and nothing else... Isntead of try to replace `VariableDeclaratorSyntax` try to replace the corresponding `LocalVariableStatementSyntax` to `UsingStatementSyntax` and then add a other `LocalVariableStatementSyntax`.

Comment: snippet is defined as that using () statement in the top of my post, as a string - I'm not sure whether that's the right way to do it either.. It's type after ParseExpression is IdentifierNameSyntax.
In all honesty, I didn't realize it should've been done by a replace and an add rather than a replace, even if the thing I want to replace it with is 2 statements in one block if that makes sense.

Comment: `SyntaxFactory.ParseExpression` can only parse expressions, not statements, and certainly not a sequence of two statements. You can use `SyntaxFactory.ParseStatement` to parse a single statement.